# Need help in making this model

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAtxP.png)
I have got an assignment, I did it properly with HTML and CSS but as soon as I add bootstrap's CDN things get change
The code is here

```css
header,
.extra-data {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

header .profile-thumbnail {
  width: 140px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

header .profile-name {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

header .follow-btn {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
}

header .follow-btn button {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

header .follow-btn button:hover {
  background-color: #9C2E9F;
}

header h3,
header h4 {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}

#inner p {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#inner hr {
  margin: 20px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  opacity: 0.1;
}

.extra-data .stats {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.extra-data .stats strong {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.extra-data .stats .likes {
  margin-left: 10px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <header>
    <img src="https://github.com/abhitnc/HTML-CSS-Assignment/blob/master/images/Deloitte-Logo.png?raw=true" alt="Quincy Larson's profile picture" class="profile-thumbnail" height="80" width="145">
    <div class="profile-name">
      <h3>MANAGER, MARKETING BUSINESS STRATEGY</h3>
      <h4><span>Choice Hotels</span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<span>Rockville, MD</span></h4>
      <p>Markting Strategy, SPSS, Sales &amp; Distribution , Market Sizing</p>
    </div>
    <div class="follow-btn">
      <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
  </header>
  <hr>
  <div class="extra-data">
    <div class="stats">
      <div class="posted-date">
        <strong><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></strong> 2 days ago&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      </div>
      <div class="experience">
        <strong><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i></strong> 0-2 years&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      </div>
      <div class="category">
        <strong><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i></strong> Project Management&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      </div>
      <div class="jobstatus">
        <strong><i class="fa fa-black-tie"></i></strong> Full-time&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      </div>
      <div class="visa">
        <strong><i class="fa fa-flag-checkered"></i></strong> H-1B
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

things are working well before implementing the bootstrap's CND
as soon as I add bootstrap the logo goes up and submits button falls down

Things also I want the hoverable text same as given in the model image
The whole box/model pops-up when user hover on it
the background-color of the button should change
if possible please give icon of USA's flag

Comment: Please explain  more what do you want to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I guess is why did you add Bootstrap CDN after you wrote your code?
You should always implement your frameworks first.

Your issue stems from writing your code with flex and CSS. I believe it's basically looking for the bootstrap key words. Bootstrap uses its own set of key words for styling in HTML and CSS. I hope this helped explain your problem a little bit.

This link should help solve your placement issues.
http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is a framework that comes with its own functions, formatting, and styling. It sounds like it's overriding your layout. You have to use their proper classes to call out elements to make it work. If you wanted to customize it further, your custom CSS would go after declaring Bootstrap. There are Bootstrap sandbox sites out there if you wanted to do some quick tests. https://www.bootply.com/new  Good luck!